# c# check in which TabPage is TextBox

Tags: c#, foreach, tabcontrol

I don't even know who to explain this using my English :) but I'll try...

I have TabControl1 with 3 TabPages (for ex. page1, page2, page3)

I did foreach loop for check what textboxs are enabled:

```
foreach (TabPage tp in tabControl1.TabPages)
       {
           foreach (Control textboxy in tp.Controls)
           {
               if (textboxy is TextBox)
               {

                   if (textboxy.Enabled)
                   {

                       if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textboxy.Text))
                       { ...
```

Now, I need to know in which TabPage is my enabled textbox to send report:

```
                           // ------ report ---------//

                           string userID = LoginForm.UserID;
                           string name;
                           string computerName = textboxy.Name;
                           string computer = computerName;

                       }

                          string whichTabPage = ...? ;  <- HERE 

                          (there is connectionstring)

                    ...}
               ..}
```

Now, i must know in what TabPage is enabled textbox and store it in variable for ex.:

```
            string whichTabPage = ?;
```

Report have to include: TabPage Name, Enabled TextBox Name and text in TextBox.

Comment: cant you still use the variable tp? which is your TabPage? tp.Name ?

Comment: Just wrap this lot in a function and return `tp` where you HERE is. That's it.

Comment: Thanks you guys for ur tips. I fogot about my variable tp.
I just did tp.Name.ToString(); that's all what i need :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something ike this...

```
string whichTabPage=String.Empty;
foreach (TabPage tp in tabControl1.TabPages)
  if (textboxy.Enabled)
  {
    whichTabPage = tp.Name;
  }
next
```

You could also use `tp.Text` instead of `tp.Name` if preferred

Comment: thanks. Like i said in first comment. I did: tp.Name.ToString();

Comment: You wouldn't need to use ToString() with tp.Name, Name is already a string

Comment: When im not using ToString() it shows me: {TabName} but if I add toString() result is TabName.